# admin gem stopped working after couple of push commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My admin gem has stopped working and my confused because I did not edit anything. I have tried updating the gem and it was working fine a couple of push commands ago.

I did not know what to show you guys, so I will put anything you guys ask.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it must shows some errors if it doesn't works. Check console also for errors.

Comment: I would suggest you to trace the commits and go back to the commit where everything was working and then work your way above one commit at a time to find the problem. Without any logs its not possible to guess what might cause the break.